# How do you switch spellchecker language in WebView2 (WinForms)?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, webview2

I have been working on a text editor based on WebView2 control.

It seems like only language that is supported is English. There was a similar post made already ( [How can I change the language used for spell checking in Microsoft Edge/WebView2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274495/how-can-i-change-the-language-used-for-spell-checking-in-microsoft-edge-webview2) ) but it does not solve this issue.

Using the recommended solution CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions.Language only changes the language in the context menu, the spellchecker still underlines non English words.

Is there anyone that has the same problem and was able to fix it? Maybe this isn't possible? Any input would be greatly appreciated.